# Odd margin around imput type text

Tags: html, css

I had two input type text positioned relatively. They have no margin but as you can see there are 5px of space between them.

[image]

There is the html

```
<form id="form_registrazione" action="registrazione_utente.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input placeholder="Nome*" id="input_nome" type="text" name="nome" maxlength="80"/>
    <input placeholder="Cognome*" id="input_cognome" type="text" name="cognome" maxlength="80" />
</form>
```

And there the style

```
#form_registrazione{

width: 500px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
position:relative;  

}

#input_nome {

position:relative;
border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
width: 240px;
height: 35px;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 5px;
transition: 0.3s;

}

#input_nome:focus {

outline: none;
border: solid 1px #707070;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;

}

#input_cognome {

position:relative;
width: 240px;
height: 35px;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 5px;
transition: 0.3s;
border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;

}

#input_cognome:focus {

outline: none;
border: solid 1px #707070;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #969696;

}
```

I've also tried to put

```
-webkit-appaerance:none;
appaerance:none;
```

but nothing has changed.

I hope you can help me

Comment: Please provide your complete html with at least parent container.

Comment: As @Paulie_D Mentioned this question as duplicate then please check the solution there.

Comment: Thank you very much, i had searched but i couldn't find this answer!